# Why must a + or - be surrounded with whitespace from within the Calc() method?

Tags: css, css-calc

Recently I've started using the calc(...) method within CSS.  I quickly learned that code such as: `width: calc(100%-2)` will not work, though adding white-space before and after the `-` operator will fix the problem and the calc method will function properly.

After doing a bit of research I found multiple blog posts reference that the white-space is required and many have even pointed to the specification ([CSS3 8.1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-syntax)) which states:

> In addition, whitespace is required on both sides of the + and -
>   operators. (The * and / operaters can be used without whitespace
>   around them.)

Now, clearly, the spec tells us that these operators must be wrapped in white-space, but why?  I've read further within the spec (through sections 8.1.2-4) and if it's explained in these additional portions, I'm not understanding the reasoning.

In simple terms, could someone explain why it was specified that `calc(100% - 1)` or even `calc(100%/2)` is acceptable syntax but not `calc(100%-1)`?

Comment: I would assume it is so that you can use negative numbers in calculations.

Comment: @Festive I don't get why you need negative numbers there?

Comment: @FestiveTurnip That's not a good assumption. Spaces are hardly required to tell a binary `-` from a unary `-`. You'll not that no other language requires you to write `3 - 2` instead of `3-2`.

Comment: In fact, rather than requiring whitespace around binary operators, CSS simply disallows whitespace between a sign and a number. This is true everywhere, including `calc()`, `:nth-child(An+B)` and simple length values like `-2em`.

Comment: Fun fact: Right now in Chrome, `100-3*20` is just parsed as `100` and treated as if you didn't do a subtraction or multiplication at all. In Safari, it just breaks the calc value entirely.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The `-` character is one of the allowed characters in CSS idents. Judging by the resolution given [here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Jul/0109.html), it seems they wanted to prevent syntactic ambiguities that could arise from using `-` without whitespace, especially with keyword values such as `min-content` (although AFAIK keyword values aren't yet allowed within `calc()` — correct me if I'm wrong).

[Not everyone agrees](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Jul/0119.html) with this resolution, though.

Comment: Very interesting.  I guess this could make sense, but a good parser should be able to resolve these issues.  (But maybe not, since CSS is different than traditional computational code (e.g. C, C#, Java, etc.))  I guess they just through the plus-sign in there because `+` and `-` often go together?

Comment: @RLH: How would you resolve something like `min-content-2em`? Should that be interpreted as a single ident (which would almost certainly result in an invalid declaration), or should it reluctantly match `min-content` as a keyword value before consuming the rest of the tokens? I reckon even a human reader would have trouble parsing that.

Comment: I see your point. Hmm, me thinks allowing for `-` in idents could be bad syntax design.  What's wrong with throwing `_` all over the place, instead, like every other sane language! :P But, I digress, my comments are outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @RLH: The *real* bad design is that we have a single ASCII ["hyphen-minus"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm) character on our keyboards :P

Answer (score 39):

The [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Expressions) explains it quite well:

> **Note**: The `+` and `-` operators must always be surrounded by whitespace. The operand of `calc(50% -8px)` for instance will be parsed as a percentage followed by a negative length, an invalid expression, while the operand of `calc(50% - 8px)` is a percentage followed by a minus sign and a length. Even further, `calc(8px + -50%)` is treated as a length followed by a plus sign and a negative percentage.
>
> The `*` and `/` operators do not require whitespace, but adding it for consistency is allowed, and recommended.

Comment: I think this is also where I was getting confused.  Example: Consider `100% +2px`, which could resolve to `100% 2px`.  This doesn't make any sense, in context.  Ergo, any case where a `+` or `-` exists (within a calc function`) should be considered an associative operation (ignoring the whole usage of the `-` symbol within idents.)  Again, I maybe missing something here, but I think a good interpreter could properly resolve at least the plus sign?

Comment: It'd be awesome if my Sass/CSS Linter was able to catch this

Answer (score 12):

I think you should first consider how do CSSs identify a length. A length is defined as an optional sign followed by a module and an optional unit of measure (although many properties actually require it):

```
<CSSlength> := [<sign>]<module>[<unit>]
```

So, for example, valid CSS lengths are:

```
-3px
100em
+10pc
0
91
5%
```

Defining a length like this, the CSS engine parses the following:

```
calc(100% -1px);
```

as a length followed by another length. In this case it would be `100%` followed by `-1px`, which doesn't make sense to `calc()` at all. This is also explained in the relative [MDN documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

In order to put two lengths in relation you need to use a distinct operator, therefore, following the above logic, you'll need to use whitespaces:

```
calc(100% - 1px);
```