# CSS3 - progressive scaling height/min-height

Tags: css, responsive, scaling

I frequently use progressive font scaling when creating hybrid mobile apps to ensure that I get reasonable displays on ancient devices with small screens as well as more modern devices that offer a lot more screen real estate.  Typically, this works really well

```
@media (min-height:500px)
{
 body
 {
  font-size:calc(10px + ((100vh - 500px)/500)*4);
 }
}

@media (min-height:1000px)
{
 body
 {
  font-size:14px;
 }
}
```

which smoothly scales up the font size from a minimum of 10px to a maximum of 14px.  Today, I had a rather different requirement - clamping the height of an HTML div element - in a parent with `display:grid`, for full disclosure.  I naively tried the following

```
@media (min-height:500px)
{
 .gridRow > div
 {
  height:calc(32px +((100vh - 500px)/500)*32);
 }
}

 @media (min-height:1000px)
 {
  .gridRow > div
  {
   height:64px;
  }
 }
```

only to find that it got ignored by the browser.  Inspecting the element in the Chrome console revealed that the rule had been struck out as being invalid by Chrome?  I cannot see that I have a typo here.  So why is this happening?

Comment: `calc(32px +((100vh - 500px)/500)*32)` --> `calc(32px + ((100vh - 500px)/500)*32)`

Comment: @TemaniAfif could you elaborate?  I cannot see that you have suggested anything different from what I currently have

Comment: you are missing a space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this as an issue owing to a missing whitespace as pointed out by @TemaniAsif.  To provide a complete explanation for anyone else who runs into this thread - the point is that in CSS a length can be preceded by an optional + or - sign.  Without a space the - is interpreted as "belonging" to the length.

For a more thorough explanation see this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34419813/why-must-a-or-be-surrounded-with-whitespace-from-within-the-calc-method).  The MDN docs highlight this issue too though perhaps not as clearly as explained by @MarcoBonelli in the SO thread referred to above.